# How to calculate Equivalent Width of a spectrum with continuum at 0

Tags: data-analysis, spectroscopy, spectra

I am trying to calculate the Equivalent Width of emission lines of a spectrum whose continuum is at 0, making the calculation of the EW impossible.

I have the spectrum of a transient in a galaxy, so I am subtracting the galactic spectrum to study the emission lines, but, by doing so, the continuum level of the resulting spectrum is at 0. I am fitting the lines with multiple gaussians and calculating the EW as flux/continuum, but being the continuum around 0 the EW values become gigantic.

Comment: Don't subtract the continuum !

Comment: I have to subtract the continuum to have the "pure" transient spectrum, rather than transient+galaxy

Comment: Well then if there really is no continuum then equivalent width is meaningless.